# Move git HEAD without changing anything else

Tags: git, git-reset

I want to move `HEAD`, and only do that.

This means I want to keep untouched:

- Index (a.k.a. cache / staging area)
- Working tree
- Commit to which the current branch reference points

`git reset --soft` does the first two, but not the last.

Is there a way to do this without creating a new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `git` plumbing command `update-ref`:

`git update-ref --no-deref HEAD $hash`

(`$hash` can be a SHA1, hash short form (eg `1c93`), tag or reference)

---

It's polite to leave a message in the `reflog` about what changed. To do this, create an alias:

```
head = "!p=\"$(git log -n1 --oneline --decorate)\" && git update-ref --no-deref -m \"Move HEAD from $p\" HEAD \"$1\" #" # Move HEAD to specified commit-ish
```

Then when you:

`git head 1c93`

the `reflog` will contain something like:

> `1c93601 HEAD@{0}: Move HEAD from fd88175 (HEAD -> master, tag: oldhead, origin/master) Add diff-highlight and icdiff`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing:

```
echo $(git rev-parse $commit) > $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/HEAD
```

But it is discouraged.

Comment: Did you try your first suggestion? It moves the branch reference for me.

Why is the second form discouraged?

Comment: @TomHale Because there is no check performed by git, so it is a little harsh. If you try that, make sure to backup before.

Comment: What checks are skipped and how could this cause an issue?

Comment: This just creates a "detached HEAD" scenario, right?